# Most efficient way to distribute inference of trained keras model using pandas_udf, two models in one go

Tags: python, tensorflow, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

Using python3.8, pyspark3.4, tensorflow2.11

Say I have two models I want to make predictions with. My first approach was to use two separate pandas_udf function to make two predictions.

```
@pandas_udf()
def pred1(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    model = load_model()
    for features in iterator:
        df = pd.concat(features, axis=1)
        yield pd.Series(model.predict(df.values, batch_size=10000).reshape(-1))

@pandas_udf()
def pred2(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    model = load_model().get_layer("model_within_model")
    
    for features in iterator:
        df = pd.concat(features, axis=1)
        yield pd.Series(model.predict(df.values, batch_size=10000).reshape(-1))

pdf = pdf.withColumn("score_1", pred1(*cols))
pdf = pdf.withColumn("score_2", pred2(*cols))
```

So now I am trying to make this more efficient. Which would be possible if I get answers to following questions.

1. Is it possible to yield a dataframe? (I know it  is possible to return however I'm guessing yielding requires less memory thus I need to yield...)

So maybe I could to something like

```
@pandas_udf()
def pred(Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> DataFrame:
    model1 = load_model()
    model2 = model1.get_layer("model_within_model")
    for features in iterator:
        df = pd.concat(features, axis=1)
        df['score_1'] = model1.predict(df.values, batch_size=10000)
        df['score_2'] = model2.predict(df.values, batch_size=10000)
        yield df

pdf = pdf.pred(*cols)
```

2. In the for-loop of pandas_udf function it seems to make predictions on subset of rows, which I'm guessing is distributed to each workers. Does spark handle this in most efficient manner or do I need to configure number of rows each worker gets?

Or if there are other optimizations(both memory and computation speed) that I could do, please let me know!